# context menu does not appears

Tags: java, android

have a look at the code below...why isnt my context menu being created ??? what may b the cause of this...?

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflator = getMenuInflater();

    inflator.inflate(R.menu.contextmenudisplayer, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.delete:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

          String s = (String) ((Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position))
                    .getString(2);
          Log.v("ID is", s);

    default:

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is the code of the xml file from the context menu displayer
`contextmenudisplayer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:title="Delete Message">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:title="Forward">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register the menu with this method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View)

Read this page, it explains everything:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html